# Do something to array elements with exception of one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to ask is there a simple way of doing something to array elements with exception of one specific element in javascript.

Example:

```
var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
```

I wanna run method or something else on all array elements except on

```
myArray.indexOf(myArray[2]);
```

What is the simplest way to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not correctly formatted code in post. I was writing from my phone. Will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be like this

```
var exceptionIndex = son value;
var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];

function someFunction(index){
  myArray.splice(index,1);
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    // do something
  }
}


someFunction(exceptionIndex);
```

Comment: splice is a nice method

Comment: This one is nice. Tnx.
I would like to know is this much slower than just using conditional statement in for loop to skip index that i need to skip? 
How can I check that speed myself?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use the great old `for` loop to iterate over the array and check for matched value.

```
var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];

for(var i = 0, len = myArray.length;i<len;i++) {
    if(i!==2) {
        // do something..
    }
}
```

Comment: Well i did not think of it for one thing. :)
Besides i was sure that there must be some native simple way of achieving "Do stuff to all array elements, except ones a provide as argument/s".
Is this way much faster that first answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like this

```
myArray.forEach(function(currentValue, currentIndex, actualArray) {
    if (currentIndex !== 2) {
        ...
    }
});
```

The `forEach` function, applies the function passed as a parameter to each and every value of the Array. It passes three parameters to the function, they are as follows

- the element value
- the element index
- the array being traversed

Answer (score 0):

Option A:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (i === 2)
        continue;

    // do something    
}
```

Option B:

```
myArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (index === 2)
        return;

    // do something 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray
    .filter(function(val, idx) {
        return idx !== 2;
    })
    .forEach(function(val) {
        myfunc(val);
    })
;
```